# .csv file not showing on flashdrive form windows

Tags: usb

I exported to.csv on windows 10 to a flashdrive. The driveopens on Ubuntu but the .csv file doesn't show?

List item

Comment: Have the file system of your flash drive checked for consistency with disk checking tools.

Comment: Does windows see the `.csv` file and can you open it with notepad, etc.